# For-loop for discounting bond coupons

Tags: python, finance

Quick question on how to write a for-loop to give me the present value (i.e. discounted value) of all coupons. My code looks like this:

i want a for-loop to do the operation

```
c[0]*np.exp(-r*1)
c[1]*np.exp(-r*2)
c[2]*np.exp(-r*3)
```

and so on (the number times -r is always the index +1).
i want a sum of all values e.g. using x+= the for-loop iteration

```
c=[7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5]
r=0.071
PVx=0 

for i in c:
    print(i)
    year = c.index(i)+1
    print(year)
    PV=c[i]*np.exp(-r*year)
    PVx += PV 
    print(PVx)
```

Somehow I'm getting the error code "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float" for my PV variable.
In essence, I want to have each value in my list be multiplied by np.exp(-r* index position +1) and then to get the sum :S

EDIT:

My new code

```
import numpy as np
c=[7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5]
r=0.071
PVx=0 

for i in c:
    year = c.index(i)+1
    print(year)
    PV=i*np.exp(-r*year)
    PVx += PV
    print(PVx)
```

keeps printing the year as 1 (meaning c.index(i) yields 0 +1 = 1), while I would expect it to go from 1 to 7. I guess that my problem right now.

Comment: Trying printing out `i` at the top of the loop. That should make this clearer.

Comment: `for i in c` is iterating through the _values_ in `c`, not some index counter. The error doesn't make sense because you should be getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float`. Something is missing.

Comment: Okay so I printed `i` at the top and changed the `c[i+1]` into an index function, which now gives me a different error, which I understand semantically :D but not the reasoning why I cant do the operation on a float.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My new code [...] keeps printing the year as 1 (meaning c.index(i) yields 0 +1 = 1), while I would expect it to go from 1 to 7.*

`list.index(i)` returns the first index where `i` appears, or -1 if `i` isn't in the list.

---

NumPy solution:

```py
import numpy as np

r = 0.071

arr_1 = np.full(shape=7, fill_value=7.5)
print(arr_1)

arr_2 = np.exp(-r * np.arange(1, arr_1.shape[0] + 1))
print(arr_2)

arr_3 = arr_1 * arr_2
print(arr_3)
print(arr_3.sum())
```

Output:

```
[7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5 7.5]
[0.93146189 0.86762126 0.80815614 0.75276664 0.70117344 0.65311634
 0.60835298]
[6.98596419 6.50715942 6.06117103 5.64574984 5.25880082 4.89837257
 4.56264738]
39.919865247574606
```

---

Looping solution:

```py
import math
from pprint import pprint

r = 0.071

vals = [7.5 * math.exp(-r * i) for i in range(1, 8)]

pprint(vals)
pprint(sum(vals))
```

Output:

```
[6.985964190956941,
 6.507159423644355,
 6.0611710291236625,
 5.645749835296472,
 5.258800824064293,
 4.898372565905067,
 4.562647378583822]
39.919865247574606
```

---

I'm not entirely certain that I understood what you're trying to do, so let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: thanks so much for taking your time to go through two different solutions. just out of interest, would you know how to specifically work around my list.index problem? I know for-loops are avoided for reasons of ineffeciency, but I'm curious as to how I could still use my structure within a for-loop :D

Comment: @germany I believe [this comment by @roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625688/for-loop-for-discounting-bond-coupons/60626177?noredirect=1#comment107258077_60625688) pointed out the issue far before me.

Answer (score 0):

the error explains the issue:"`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float`" a float is a number with a decimal i.e not a whole number. for exampe 7.5. that's your issue.